# Map overlay in android app

Tags: android, google-maps

[image]I am trying to add a pin image to certain places to my map in my android application, but then there is a big semi transparent rectangle that appears over my map, that does not allow me to interact with the main map, I have tried using map overlay or itemized map overlay, but i get the same result, I dont know if this is because of the image, or this is usually what happens when someone adds an overlay to his map.
PS I am using a .png image

If anyone could help me i would be so grateful
thanks

this is the itemized overlay class

```
private class MirItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

        private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

        public MirItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return mOverlays.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return mOverlays.size();
        }

        public void addOverlayItem(OverlayItem overlayItem) {
            mOverlays.add(overlayItem);
            populate();
        }

        public void addOverlayItem(int lat, int lon, String title) {
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, title, null);
            addOverlayItem(overlayItem);
        }

    }
```

and this is how I use it in the oncreate method in my map activity

```
Drawable makerDefault =this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.redcircle);
 MirItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MirItemizedOverlay(makerDefault); 
  GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (49.9736518*1E6), (int) (7.114648   *1E6));
   OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "hotspot1", null);
  itemizedOverlay.addOverlayItem((int) (49.9736518*1E6), (int) (7.114648 *1E6), "hotspot1");
```

Comment: a code snippet or screenshot could be helpful to understand...

Comment: ok I added some code and I will a screenshot for the output now

Comment: I will, I am sorry I am new here didnt know I should be doing that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add your `itemizedOverlay` to `MapView` overlays:

```
MapView mapView = ...;
mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
```